# I am empty but what am I really?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> I exist because nothing exists.
>
> Ahead of me a cold breeze
>
> behind me a raging warmth
>
> I am the end of the beginning as much as the start of it

**What am I?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am I:

> Ginnungagap?

I exist because nothing exists.

> This line leads to something that is empty, hence an abyss is a good pick

Ahead of me a cold breeze

> From the poem Völuspá, it is said that the abyss was so cold it could freeze a man

behind me a raging warmth

> Surt was the warrant of the fire realm Muspelheim, he cast fire into the abyss

I am the end of the beginning as much as the start of it

> Odin killed Ymir and threw his corpse into the abyss, making Midgard

Comment: Yes it was, could you elaborate it more?

Comment: Sure, i replied quickly because I had to leave my computer

Answer (score 0):

Could I be

> the **Big Bang**

I exist because nothing exists

> The big bang is the essence of all existence

A head of me a cold breeze

> If you see the big bang as an ongoing explosion, there is nothing a head but nothingness

behind me a raging warmth

> Keeping in mind the same assumption the expanding explosion will create warmth because physics

I am the end of the beginning as much as the start

> The begining of all was the big bang after that everything started. Start of the beginning could be thet some view the big bang as a never ending series of explosion reabsorbing and starting back again.

Comment: fairly close but I in another context (norse Mythology)

Answer (score 0):

Is it :

> The edge of the universe ?

```
I exist because nothing exists.
```

> The creator needs "space" (no puns intended) to create

```
Ahead of me a cold breeze
```

> Ahead of it, there is nothing, no light, no heat

```
behind me a raging warmth
```

> Behind it, there is something, must been warmer than "nothing"

```
I am the end of the beginning as much as the start of it
```

> Self explanatory

Comment: Fairly close as well, try looking this up in norse mythology context

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> Allvater (Fimbultyr)

because

```
I exist because nothing exists.
```

> He was the first to create everything

```
Ahead of me a cold breeze
```

> The Fimbulvetr

```
behind me a raging warmth
```

> The fights before Fimbulvetr

```
I am the end of the beginning as much as the start of it
```

> Created the world, which was destroyed by Ragnarök (end) and then rebuild (start) by Allvater

Comment: I forgot to take the title 'I am empty but what am I really?' in consideration. This makes Saneas answer more fitting.